# Current best methods for targeting multiple screen sizes

Tags: css, html, mobile

I'm  looking for some articles on creating a website for multiple screen sizes - e.g. desktop, iPad, iPhone, other mobile device. With this area moving so fast, it's hard to know if what I've been reading is several "best practices" behind or not. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found these three articles to be an excellent resource for building responsive, fluid, multi-device websites:

**A-List Apart article on Fluid Grids:**
http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fluidgrids/

**Smashing Magazine article on Responsive web Design** (*references A-List Apart's article on same subject*):
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/

*And,* **Smashing Magazine's '*How to use Media Queries*':**
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

Comment: No problem at all Sio. All the best with it =)

Answer (score 2):

Check out W3C's [Mobile Web](http://www.w3.org/standards/webdesign/mobilweb) documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This is my favorite article on the this sort of thing.

From A List Apart: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/

Answer (score 0):

Check out CSS3 Media queries; http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/CSS3MediaQueries/Default.html